# React-Redux data-flow between Smart and Dumb Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Im quite new to React stack and I want to understand how does data flows in Smart/Dumb Components.
Here is my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/viyepo/8/edit?html,js,output) to illustrate the problem.

I want to get value from input to clickCallback and dispatch "ADD_TODO_ITEM" action to add todo item with inputed name. Normally in React data flows downstream and Im not quite sure how to resolve this. I have idea to add onChange callback to this input and store latest value, this will work I checked it but I almost 100% sure that it is not correct approach.

Answer (score 2):

Having a clickCallback and dispatching "ADD_TODO_ITEM" action with the new item is exactly what you want to do and is totally idiomatic for flux.  When the store data updates the component will re-render itself.

You are updating the data at the source and the changes flow down the rendering pipeline.

As for getting the value from the input field, depends on you.  The simplest thing would be to simply use some DOM manipulation function (maybe give the text field an id).  If you do the following than the clickCallback handler will get the normal event and you can identify the button as the event.target. From there you can get the the text field value pretty easily (it's next to the button in the DOM).

```
      <button onClick={this.props.clickCallback.bind(this)}>Add</button>
```

I can't speak to the way the reducer works.  I use a different flux implementation [alt](https://github.com/goatslacker/alt). In that it's pretty typical to append a new item to a collection in a store.

Comment: Yeah, but how do I get value of input field to clickCallback?

Comment: Also what do You think about "let next_state = _.cloneDeep(state);" ?
I see many people using different functions to make sure that thier reducers are pure, but isn't it simpler to just create cloned object and modify it?

Comment: You rarely want to do a _deep_ clone of your state.  If you have nested data, you will need to do _shallow_ clones for each level of nesting, but you want as much of the state contents to be the same as possible.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#performance-clone-state.

Comment: Thanks. It explained a lot.